# multiples proyectos en un repositorios Gh pages y angular

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

estoy con un problema con github pages y angular por que para la facultad nos pidieron que lo subamos de esta manera pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.
tengo un repositorio que contiene varias carpetas ejemplo: Proyectos/tp1/EntregaFinal

asi tengo tp2/entregafinal hasta 5 entregas, el problema surge que no puedo levantar mi web de angular en github pages, instale el cli de github pages y estuve intentando varias formas para levantarlo y no tuve solucion tenemos en github levantado el link de usuario.github.io/Proyecto, si entro al link usuario.github.io/Proyecto/TP2/EntregaFinal solo me levanta el readme.md de angular
alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizas sea un tema de compilacion de proyecto.

**Si esperas mostrar el proyecto dentro de Angular jamas vas a ver nada.** Angular es un marco de trabajo, no una aplicacion productiva.

En tu proyecto Angular debes crear la version de produccion escribiendo en la consola: `ng build --prod` Despues de compilar esta version productiva queda guardada en la carpeta `./dist` a nivel de proyecto.

El código compilado de esta carpeta es el que subes a Github y le aplicas la configuración para que sea `Github pages` si no quieres problemas de Git local tratando de subir la carpeta dist puedes comprimirla en Zip y luego subirlo compreso.

Te dejo una imagen de como se ve el resultado de `./dist` en GitHub lista para usar en Pages.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo añadiría que es necesario revisar el .gitignore, por si acaso está configurado pa no subir los compilados.